# Ao selecionar um radio button como sim, colocar os outros como não

Tags: javascript, html

eu tenho várias respostas de questões em radio button, eu gostaria de que quando voce selecionasse sim em um, os outros ficasse checados como não

por exemplo das alternativas

```html
<div class="row" id="row_multipla_escolha">
    <div id="alternative_0" class="col-12 d-flex template-multipla-escolha p-0">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Nome</label>
                <div class="form-control">questão 1</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label>
                É a correta? </label><br />
            <label> <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="correct[0][is_correct]" value="yes"> Sim </label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label> <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="correct[0][is_correct]" value="no"> Não </label>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="row_multipla_escolha">
    <div id="alternative_0" class="col-12 d-flex template-multipla-escolha p-0">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Nome</label>
                <div class="form-control">questão 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label>
                É a correta? </label><br />
            <label> <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="correct[1][is_correct]" value="yes"> Sim </label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label> <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="correct[1][is_correct]" value="no"> Não </label>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="row_multipla_escolha">
    <div id="alternative_0" class="col-12 d-flex template-multipla-escolha p-0">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Nome</label>
                <div class="form-control">questão 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label>
                É a correta? </label><br />
            <label> <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="correct[2][is_correct]" value="yes"> Sim </label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label> <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="correct[2][is_correct]" value="no"> Não </label>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta removendo o código apresentado e no lugar dele postando um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor proveito do site.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Para realizar essa funcionalidade, você precisará adicionar algum código JavaScript para manipular os radio buttons quando um deles for selecionado como "Sim". Aqui está um exemplo de como você pode fazer isso:

```html
<script>
    // Obtém todos os elementos de radio button com a classe "form-control"
    const radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"].form-control');

    // Adiciona um ouvinte de evento para cada radio button
    radioButtons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('change', function() {
            // Verifica se o botão selecionado é "Sim"
            if (this.value === 'yes') {
                // Percorre todos os outros radio buttons
                radioButtons.forEach(otherButton => {
                    // Verifica se o radio button atual não é o mesmo que foi selecionado
                    if (otherButton !== this) {
                        // Define o valor como "Não"
                        otherButton.value = 'no';
                        // Desmarca o radio button
                        otherButton.checked = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Você pode adicionar esse código JavaScript ao final do seu arquivo HTML, logo antes do fechamento da tag `<body>`. Ele irá percorrer todos os radio buttons com a classe "form-control" e, quando um deles for selecionado como "Sim", irá desmarcar os outros radio buttons definindo o valor como "Não".

Certifique-se de incluir o código JavaScript em todas as páginas em que você tiver esses radio buttons. Além disso, lembre-se de manter o atributo `name` correto para cada conjunto de radio buttons, para garantir que apenas um deles possa ser selecionado por vez.